# C# Budget Calculator issue with Starting money

Tags: c#

So this is my budget calculator.
It calculates how much i can earn with deposit(% per year), i can add money(earnings) and can decrease money(loosing).

In my code you have to manually tell the size of starting money.
What i need is for example in the beginning i tell my program that starting capital is 500euro. When i use deposit, it become for example 570,50. When i use earnings, i need it to start from 570,50, but in my program it will always ask again, what is your starting capital. I need to do it automatically somehow. Sorry for my bad english and here is the whole code :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int menu;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1 - '%'");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - '+'");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - '-'");
            Console.WriteLine("0 - iziet");

            Console.Write("Menu: ");
            menu = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (menu > 0 && menu < 4)
            {
                switch (menu)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            Console.Write("Noguldamā naudas summu: ");
                            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Procentu likme (0 - 100): ");
                            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Laiks (gadi): ");
                            int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            double d = Procenti(a, b, c);
                            Console.WriteLine("\nNaudas summa pēc {0} gadiem būs {1}\n", c, d);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        {
                            Console.Write("Sakuma nauda: ");
                            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Cik nopelnijat: ");
                            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            double d = Pluss(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine("Tagadejais budzhets ir: {0} euro", d);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        {
                            Console.Write("Sakuma nauda: ");
                            double a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                            Console.Write("Cik izterejat: ");
                            double b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                            double d = Minuss(a, b);
                            Console.WriteLine("Tagadejais budzhets ir: {0} euro", d);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ludzu ievadiet ciparus 0,1,2,3 - parejie cipari ir arpus robezham!");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        } while (menu != 0);
    }




    //FUNKCIJASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    static double Procenti(double a, double b, int c)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            a = (a * (b / 100) + a);
        }
        return a;
    }
    static double Pluss(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    static double Minuss(double a, double b)
    {

        return a - b;
    }
}
```

Comment: A few points: 1) your program will die horribly if the user enters a non-numeric value when you're at the menu or when entering values. 2) Having _Pluss_ and _Minuss_ as separate functions doesn't seem to make much sense unless you plan to be able to change what plus and minus do. If you do plan to do this then the names are misleading as that would no longer be their purpose. 3) You do not appear, at any point, to be storing a balance and your program flow is set to always ask for numbers in each of the cases in which the menu option was not zero.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the value inside a variable.
and before to start the transactions you ask the user for the value :

```
int menu;
float stored_money;
Console.Write("Enter the Initial Value: ");
stored_money = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
do
{
```

and in the functions use this variable

```
static double Pluss(double b)
{
    stored_money = stored_money + b;
    return stored_money;
}
static double Minuss(double b)
{
    stored_money = stored_money - b;
    return stored_money;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically it looks like you need to save your balance amount somewhere in your code, because right now you're entering it from console in each menu point.

Something like (note I've omitted most of code):

```
int menu;
decimal amount;

do
{
   .... //your code
    case 1:
    {
        Console.Write("Noguldamā naudas summu: ");
        amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
       .... //your code
        decimal d = Procenti(a, b, c);
        amount += d;
    }
   case 2:
   {      
       Console.Write("Cik nopelnijat: ");
       decimal b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       amount = Pluss(amount, b);
       Console.WriteLine("Tagadejais budzhets ir: {0} euro", amount);
   }
    .... //your code
} while (menu != 0);
```

And later in all cases you should not enter amount, but use that saved value and modify it according to menu point task.

Or maybe you even should introduce new menu point to set initial amount and don't enter it in point 1 (if point 1 can be called multiple times) - it depends on your calculator logic and it's up to you.

Note - it's better to use `decimal` rather that `int` and `double` for financial calculations as it is designed to store full possible precision.

Comment: Can you write a code for this one? "Or maybe you even should introduce new menu point to set initial amount and don't enter it in point 1 (if point 1 can be called multiple times)" I would love to see that!

Comment: @naathanz Hmm.... what is unclear to you in that approach? Instead of entering initial amount in point 1 (like in code sample I've wrote) - just add another point, and let's say point 1 will be now "Enter initial amount", point 2 is your former point 1 and so on. You will enter initial amount only once and in other points you will somehow modify that amount - accourding to point goal.